# 12.10 Drag and Drop not working

Tags: drag-and-drop

That's just it. I click on a file on the desktop with my mouse, drag it to another location on the desktop, or to an open folder, and....it zooms right back into the original position when I let go of the mouse button.

Am I a fool? It seems like a rather obvious question I could find with a search, but all the answers are very specific to problems I am not having.

Comment: Which program manages your desktop? Could you edit your question to provide that information?

Comment: I am using basic 12.10 Unity.

Comment: Are you still experiencing this?